# Unique 4 digit random number in C#

Tags: c#, random

I want to generate an unique 4 digit random number. This is the below code what I have tried:

**Code for generating random number**

```
//Generate RandomNo
public int GenerateRandomNo()
{
    int _min = 0000;
    int _max = 9999;
    Random _rdm = new Random();
    return _rdm.Next(_min, _max);
}
```

The problem is I have received a random no with value `241` which is not a 4 digit number. Is there any problems with the code?

Comment: Warning. If you call your function multiple times in a row you may get the same values. Better to reuse your Random object.

Comment: initialize your _min as 1000

Comment: @amitdayama  this is what I was looking for.

Comment: Maybe this article can help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730511/random-number-generator-variable-length

Comment: I have already generated all the four digit numbers, so there are no unique ones left, sorry. :-)  Seriously though: unique over what timeframe and what set of users?  And how many do you need? If you need a million unique four digit numbers you are going to be disappointed.

Comment: Note that the second argument to Random.Next is an *exclusive* upper bound.  If the intent is to generate a random integer between 0 and 9999, `_max` should be 10,000 rather than 9999.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
//Generate RandomNo
public int GenerateRandomNo()
{
    int _min = 1000;
    int _max = 9999;
    Random _rdm = new Random();
    return _rdm.Next(_min, _max);
}
```

you need a 4 digit code, start with 1000

Comment: Note that moving `Random _rdm = new Random();` directly above `public int GenerateRandomNo()` will yield better results.

Comment: In `Next (int minValue, int maxValue)` `maxValue` is the exclusive upper bound. It means that to include the value of 9999 you should set `_max` to 10000.

Comment: note, that `0-999` and `9999` won't be part of the result

Comment: return new Random().Next(1000, 9999); - this would keep it short

Answer (score 36):

```
private Random _random = new Random();

public string GenerateRandomNo()
{
    return _random.Next(0, 9999).ToString("D4");
}
```

Comment: Why is it better this way?

Comment: @Moon could you help me to explain what `.ToString("D4")` is?

Comment: @YusrilMaulidanRaji it is used to pad a number with leading zeros. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-pad-a-number-with-leading-zeros

Answer (score 9):

241 is a four digit number, if you use leading zeros: 0241.

Display the returned number with a format string like this:

`String.Format("{0:0000}", n);`

Answer (score 9):

Just one line code

```
int num = new Random().Next(1000, 9999);
```

Answer (score 6):

0 is the same as 0000.

241 is the same as 0241.

You could format the integer to a string with a leading zero.

Answer (score 3):

```
Random generator = new Random();
string number = generator.Next(1, 10000).ToString("D4");
```

Answer (score 2):

use: int _min = 1000;

or use leading 0 in case if you want 0241

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to create new list and check if this list contains any of number

```
var IdList = new List<int>();
do
{
    billId = random.Next(1, 9000);
} while (IdList.Contains(billId));
IdList.Add(billId);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int NoDigits = 4;
Random rnd = new Random();
textBox2.Text = rnd.Next((int)Math.Pow(10, (NoDigits - 1)), (int)Math.Pow(10, NoDigits) -1).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the answer from brij but with 0000 to 9999 rather than 1000 to 9999

```
string formatting = "0000"; //Will pad out to four digits if under 1000   
int _min = 0;
int _max = 9999;
Random randomNumber = new Random();
var randomNumberString = randomNumber.Next(_min, _max).ToString(formatting);
```

or if you want to minimalize lines:

```
Random randomNumber = new Random();
var randomNumberString = randomNumber.Next(0, 9999).ToString("0000");
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this you will avoid starting numbers with 00[...] and you can also specify the length.

```
string RandomNumbers(int Length)
{
    Random Rand = new Random();
    StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < Length; i++)
        SB.Append(Rand.Next(0, 9));

    return SB.ToString();
}

RandomNumbers(4) // OUTPUT: 9301, 4936, 0692, etc ...
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Comment: It is funny to see people who put downvote even if the solution works. I will update as soon as I have time, however I don't have to.

Comment: Update your answer at least a short description

Comment: @MarcoConcas I understand and hope you'll continue to contribute. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Method to generate any digits number. The loop inside will regenerate the number if it contains duplicate digits, so the random number will consist from unique digits only.

```
using System.Linq;

public static int GenerateRandomNum()
    {
        // Number of digits for random number to generate
        int randomDigits = 4;
        
        int _max = (int)Math.Pow(10, randomDigits);
        Random _rdm = new Random();
        int _out = _rdm.Next(0, _max);

        while (randomDigits != _out.ToString().ToArray().Distinct().Count())
        {
            _out = _rdm.Next(0, _max);
        }
        return _out;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can consider something like this.

```
int length = 4;
int number = 50;
string asString = number.ToString("D" + length);
```

The above code gives the result 0050.

Similarly you can try converting to string and verify.