# execute while loop only once to generate pin

Tags: c#

I want to execute while loop only once to generate pin. Now every time when i click a buton the while loop generate every time new pin. I want just one pin. 
This is my code

```
Guid PinGuid;

byte[] Arr;
UInt32 PINnum = 0;
while(PINnum.ToString().Length != 4)
{
    PinGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
    Arr = PinGuid.ToByteArray();
    PINnum = BitConverter.ToUInt32(Arr, 0);

}
textBox4.Text += PINnum.ToString();
```

UPDATE:

I found the solution.

```
string x = "";
Guid PinGuid;
byte[] Arr;
UInt32 PINnum = 0;
while(PINnum.ToString().Length != 4)
{
    PinGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
    Arr = PinGuid.ToByteArray();
    PINnum = BitConverter.ToUInt32(Arr, 0);

}
x = PINnum.ToString();
```

return x;

Comment: `if (!hasDoneBefore) { /* do it */; hasDoneBefore = true }`?

Comment: When you want to execute some code only once, why use a loop at all?

Comment: You are initializing PINnum = 0; again and again. You can make it a singleton, and assign once. If it has value, it won't get generated.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the context, I think that you should rather use an if-statement instead of a while-loop.

Just change the `while` into an `if` and see how that works.

EDIT: Actually, I think you want to add a number to the PINnum during the loop, but the PINnum is changing constantly, without adding an extra number. so the lenght will remain at 1. I think changing the current value of Pinnum to a string before adding a new one may eventually help out.

It might also be better to change the `!=` into a `<`, That way the while-loop will work properly without possible changes to continue past the 4.

Comment: If the while is changed into a if with the same condition, the code inside if doesn't run anymore, because PINum is equal to 0...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code your seem to be trying to generate a 4 digit PIN.

However you don't say whats in textbox4 at the start, so not sure how valid your = 4 is (while(PINnum.ToString().Length != 4 && textBox4.TextLength == 4)).

There are a few other issues......

So if you are looking for a 4 digit Pin generator then try here [Unique 4 digit random number in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33749543/unique-4-digit-random-number-in-c-sharp)